# I'm on the market

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Sometimes some girl says: **I'm on the market**, what does it mean?

Comment: It sounds like she's declaring that she's for sale, but hopefully that's not what she actually meant...

Comment: I've always taken it to mean: "I'm single, not currently in a committed dating relationship, and wouldn't mind the chance to start dating a decent guy." I've put several examples in comments below. I'm surprised this meaning seems so puzzling to some native speakers.

Comment: @J.R.: Apparently some native speakers don't significantly distinguish ***on*** from ***in*** in this precise context. Perhaps that's because fashion/lifestyle magazines, etc., often run features advising people how to successfully *put themselves **on** the market* (make themselves attractive to potentially-significant others as "buyers"). They won't run so many features explaining how to psych yourself up to go looking ***in** the market*, and how best to make your choice of a prospective mate once you're there.

Comment: @Fumble - Actually, I do distinguish the two. I've heard _I'm in the market for an X_ (where X might even be "new boyfriend"), but the phrase "on the market" with no qualifier means "not dating." I ran it by my wife, too, and she immediately thought the same. "What's it mean when a woman says she's ‘on the market’," I asked. "It means she's looking for a new guy," she replied, unhesitatingly.

Comment: @J.R.: Obviously if you ask *any* competent native speaker what OP's citation means, you'd get something like that definition. But if you asked *If a woman who's looking for a new guy said: "I'm XX the market", which of "on" or "in" is more likely/appropriate?*, I think that would be more enlightening. I kinda doubt anyone would ask for the meaning of the ***on*** version if they already knew the ***in*** version, therefore it makes sense to me that any answer on ELL should focus on the more common form, rather than promote/sanitise the potentially contentious non-standard usage.

Comment: @Fumble - If I was single and looking, I'd say that I was "on the market." If I was out shopping, I'd say that I'm "in the market." (I would only use "in" if I was specifying what I was in the market for; i.e.: "I'm in the market for a new significant other.") I know that's only one data point, but that's how this native speaker would say it. Moreover, if someone told me, "I'm in the market," I'd probably reply, "In the market for _what_?"

Comment: @J.R.: I'm well aware you (and obviously a few others) would make that same choice. My point is twofold. 1 - I think your position is a *minority* one. 2 - even if more than half of all native speakers took that line (which I seriously doubt), it would still be advisable for a non-native speaker to learn the usage *in conjunction with* becoming aware of the normal distinction whereby ***someone** is **in** the market* to buy/find ***something** that's **on** the market*.

Comment: I don't know where you get that it's a minority opinion, though. Your "4630 hits" link shows very little; I visited that link, and it includes hits on "in the market for a car," "in the market for an insurance company", "in the market for a new man" (which supports my assertion) – and really doesn't show much else, as the number of quotes seems to fizzle by Page 2. By the time I got to page 5, my browser read: `Page 5 of 41 results`, and only one or two of those would qualify as an example of what you deem the "relevant idiomatic expression."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17733/on-the-market-or-in-the-market/17735).

Without further context, I would assume that the girl is not seeing anyone at the moment (she is not in a relationship), and she is looking for someone to be in a relationship with.

On the other hand, she *may* indeed be telling you (on the phone for instance) that she is out shopping. (Thank you Edwin Ashworth!)

Comment: Hereabouts, if she's phoning, it means she's shopping on the outside market.

Comment: As I said, context means everything :D

Comment: Even with an outdoors market, I would still expect her to say that she was _in_ the market, no? To me, only goods laid out for sale are _on_ the market, not the people who come to buy them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I have heard people say they were _on_, _in_ or _at_ the market to describe they were surrounded by shopping possibilities. Possibly the excitement of the paradox of choice this presents influences their linguistic judgement when choosing prepositions... and a sub-optimal phone connection could also account for an _in_ heard as _on_ :)

Comment: As @JanusBahsJacquet says, a product for sale is "on the market". A person at a store is "at the market" or possibly "in the market". I've never heard someone say "I'm on the market" meaning that she is at a store. It always means that she is available for a romantic relationship, i.e. she is comparing herself to a product that is for sale. Now that I think about it, I'm surprised that that phrase hasn't been condemned as sexist and demeaning to women. But I'm sure the origin was a joke.

Comment: @Jay I think the main reason it hasn’t been condemned as sexist and demeaning to women is that it applies just as much to men—a man can be on the market just as much as a woman can. It is probably sexist, but at least it’s egalitarianly (egalitarianistically?!) sexist.

Comment: Why the downvote, I wonder?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: maybe someone is so upset about the abuse of language (strictly locational use of _on_ the market) by people around me and Edwin (although I doubt our _hereabouts_ are close) that some prescriptivist reflex made them hit the down-vote button :)

Comment: One upvote for "indeed she is out shopping." :D

Comment: It was my downvote. There are almost no circumstances where being ***on** the market* would be an idiomatically acceptable alternative to ***in** the market*. It's certainly never used *by the speaker* to mean they're currently unattached, and looking for a relationship. And I must say if I heard a native speaker say *"She's **on** the market"* I would view this as somewhat "sexist" (it would sound more like she's up for grabs on the "cattle market" where people are traded like sides of beef). And if it's "literal", it's *always* ***in***.

Comment: @Janus: [This is by far the earliest](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22standing+in+the+market+for+marriage%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) citation I can find for the idiomatic usage in the "relationship/marriage" sense. And it's quite clear from context that the ***man*** thinks of himself as being "available to be selected" by the young ladies who are ***in** the market* for a husband. No sexism there!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m sorry, but that is simply incorrect. “I’m on the market” is certainly used by speakers to indicate that they themselves are single and available. It doesn’t necessarily mean they’re _looking_ for a relationship (that would be _in_ the market [for a relationship]), but it is absolutely used, though possibly more so in AmE than BrE. It does sound like you’re up for grabs at the cattle market, and _that’s exactly what it’s meant to say_. It’s a bit jocular and it’s definitely colloquial.

Comment: @Janus: It's in the nature of this particular idiomatic usage that a few people will get the wrong end of the stick, so to speak. Thus when they *repeat* it wrongly, others who've never heard it before become slightly confused too. But ELL is here to teach "standard" usage, and you can hardly argue with the two Google Books figures I gave in my answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m not, actually. They agree with what I’m saying. What they don’t show is the difference in register between the two expressions (_in the market for_ being quite neutral, and _on the market_ being quite colloquial).

Comment: @Janus: I think we will simply have to disagree. So far as I'm concerned, unless we're talking about the ***slave** market* (which never really existed in Britain), then the figurative attribution ***in** the market* is the standard colloquial idiom when applied to *people*. Leave it few days and we'll see how the votes go (though I do sometimes worry that on ELL they can be skewed by non-native speakers).

Comment: Whether one says of oneself they are on the market (which does have a possible negative connotation, but I would not call it sexist as no sex is discriminated against), being _in_ the market for a relationship has the same connotation, except if somehow you view selling as worse than buying a person...

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "It's certainly never used by the speaker to mean they're [..] looking for a relationship." I expect [Sally Field](http://www.closerweekly.com/posts/sally-field-attempts-to-explain-her-love-life-i-m-not-taking-myself-off-the-market-37066) is a native speaker. So maybe it's the native speakers that have "skewed" the perception of this poor non-native speaker, but it took me all of 1 minute to find this. This [song](http://www.metrolyrics.com/push-upstairs-lyrics-underworld.html) seems to be written by native speakers too...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: For _on the market_ as a locative, I stumbled on [this](http://books.google.nl/books?id=NqcNoAljD8AC&pg=PT236&lpg=PT236&dq=%22I%27m+on+the+market%22&source=bl&ots=e07vahfkmk&sig=EdrGuNGR72grQP8J4k4ZurboSuI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gFiPU_nuB4it7QajsYGgCg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22I'm%20on%20the%20market%22&f=false).

Comment: @oerkelens Interesting. This coupled with Edwin’s statement makes me think it must be a Britishism that I have just never heard or noticed before. I suppose people don’t often go to actual markets anymore, but still …

Comment: Okay, so Sally Field is the exception proving the rule. But note that even in that cited context, she's quite obviously "bending" the idiomatic standard. What she actually says is *“When you get to a certain age, you’re not dating. I’m not taking myself off the market – not that I’m on the market. I’m just alive.”* She's 67 years old, rich, famous, and unattached - she *wants* to "muddy the waters" as to whether she's looking to pick a potential partner, or have a potential partner pick *her*.

Comment: Well, ok. So Two examples is not enough çause they ar ejust the exeption, and one celeb and three songwriters is all I feel like bringing to this party. The expression _is_ used, maybe not much. And even though it is as sexist as it's _in_ variation, it is evil. I won't defend it further, I see no reason.

Comment: @Fumble - "on the market" means (roughly) "available to start a dating relationship," and generally indicates the person is not dating anyone else. From an article at match.com: _the 40-something singles scene is flooded with divorced folk who are back on the market_. From a UK Daily Mail headline: _Real Housewives star LuAnn de Lesseps is back on the market after split from boyfriend_. From a dating column (addressing Are You Dating the 'Right One'?): _If your gut is telling you otherwise, it's time to get out and get back on the market!_ It's an expression the learner ought to know.

Comment: Want more? [Single and on the market?](http://digitaljournal.com/tech/technology/article/369840) ~ [Gomez recently told _Seventeen_ magazine's March issue that she is still on the market – and her standards are pretty high.](http://www.contactmusic.com/article/selena-gomez-not-dating-austin-mahone_4046618) ~ [Robert Pattinson is officially still on the market, ladies, as Rob's rumoured new squeeze Riley Keough's rep has now spoken up to deny that the pair are dating.](http://www.look.co.uk/news/robert-pattinson-riley-keough-are-not-dating) It works for men or women; celebs or ordinary people.

Comment: Oh, and apparently for royalty, too. From the _London Evening Standard_: [Prince Harry is on the market](http://www.standard.co.uk/showbiz/celebrity-news/prince-harry-is-on-the-market-7566067.html)

Comment: Or it could mean that she's standing on the roof of the market. :)

Answer (score 2):

The relevant idiomatic expression is...

> [*She's **in** the market*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she%27s%20in%20the%20market%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (4630 hits in Google Books, as opposed to [just 10 for ***...on...***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she%27s%20in%20the%20market%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22she%27s%20on%20the%20market%22&tbm=bks))

The "base" expression *to be **in** the market [for something]* means you're actively seeking to acquire *[something]*. In general, if the thing sought isn't either explicitly specified or obvious from context, it means a ***romantic partner*** or ***relationship***.

Because of the nature of that extremely common "implied" target, I imagine some people think of *"I'm in the market"* as meaning *"I am available"* (i.e. - *someone else can "acquire" **me***), since semantically it would amount to much the same thing. But that "inverted" sense never applies if context clearly indicates anything other than a *relationship*, so I'd say it's just a misreading of the expression. Also note this...

> (two couples chatting at a dinner party in December...)
>    1a: [one of couple A] *"No-one wants to be buying or selling their house in December".*
>    2a: [one of couple B] *"I wouldn't say that. We're **in** the market".*
>    2b: [one of couple B]  *"I wouldn't say that. We're **on** the market".*

2b is one of the very few contexts where ***on*** can be used at all (effectively it means ***we = our house*** is on the housing market (i.e. - **for sale**). Whereas 2a is the more standard *We're looking to **buy** a house*.

---

TL;DR: For the *literal* sense it's always ***in*** the market (or ***at*** the market). For idiomatic usages, it's always ***on*** the market = **for sale**, and ***in*** the market = seeking to **buy** (or **get** in some other way).

EDIT: It seems several people here accept "non-facetious" usage of *"I'm **on** the market"* meaning nothing more than *"I'm actively seeking a partner"*, so it's worth noting that as a possibility. But my advice would be only use it of *yourself* if you're aware of the *"I'm available to be chosen"* connotations (as opposed to *"I'm looking to make a choice"* with the standard form). And I'd certainly advise caution with the ***on*** form if you're talking about someone else.

Comment: Note that your Google Books hits actually confirm what I was saying in the comment under oerkelens’ reply: there is only one instance where ‘she’ is on the market _for a new relationship_ (and that does read very unnaturally to me); whereas the majority of the _in_ hits have a _for_ clause.

Comment: There simply is a difference in meaning between _I'm on the market_ and _I'm in the market_, and I would argue that if one is sexist (which sex is discriminated against???) so is the other. The OP asked about the form which I answered for, and the other question I linked to deals with the difference between _on_ and _in_.

Comment: There are actually only 4 different Google Books citations for *she's **on** the market* where the full context is visible, and one of those is definitely what I would call a "misuse" *(she's on the market for a boyfriend)*. Given how common the standard expression is, I really don't see the point of defending the possibility of such a non-standard usage on a *learners* site.

Comment: Perhaps there are few hits in books because the phrase is  informal, yet it abounds. If a girl told me she was "on the market," I'd take that to mean she was available to start dating. If I were single, I'd consider it a green light to ask her out; if I wasn't _on the market_ myself, I'd consider it an invitation to set her up with any single guys I might know. It may be hard to find the phrase in books, but advice columns often address it: _[After years of not dating, here’s how to get back on the market](http://lovesujeiry.com/singles/ask-sujeiry-advice/starting-over-dating-relationships/)._