# "our products are leaders in the market" or "on the market"

Tags: prepositions

> We have a portfolio of more than 40 drug products. Most of our products are leaders **on** the Russian market.

Is this **on** the correct choice of a preposition?

Would **in** work as well?

> We have a portfolio of more than 40 drug products. Most of our products are leaders **in** the Russian market.

According to the answer to *[this question,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/17733/2127)* **in** might be inappropriate. I wonder if it still can be used.

On the one hand, these products are there to be sold, so it should be **on**. On the other, we are comparing them with competitors' products, so it should be **in**. I'm a bit confused.

Now that I thought of it more, I favor **in**. It's such a hazy issue for me.

Comment: I agree, I would use "in" in this context precisely because you're comparing it to other products on the market.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we use the phrase *on the market* we are contrasting the idea that something is available to buy with the notion that it might not be available to buy:

- Are they on the market yet?

When we use a preposition phrase with *in* after the word *leader(s)*, we are indicating the area that the leader is leader in:

- He was a leader in the field of nuclear electromagnetic resonance.
- They are the leaders in their market.